# Europass 2013 Curriculum Vitae

Tags: templates, moderncv, europecv

Is there any new template for the Europass Curriculum Vitae 2013?

I'm aware of the both the [`europecv`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/europecv/) and [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) packages, but I'm looking for something with the "new" (as of July 2013) version of the Europass (templates available [here](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/en/documents/curriculum-vitae/templates-instructions)).

If it is not available yet, has anyone come up with a workaround?

//

**UPDATE**

I just received a mail from Nicola Vitacolonna (developer of `europecv`).  It seems he has officially abandoned the project due to work and family constraints. However, he is willing to help, if someone else decides to take it over.

Comment: I don't think there is one. Essentially your question asks: "Please make a template for me." I propose you raise the bounty significantly to make it more worthwhile to look at this.

Comment: You are right @Ingo, there isn't one...  The closest one came from `europecv`, but as I mentioned, it still has the old version.  Also, as you can see by the date of the first publication, this question has been around for quite a long time now, and of course I have already manage a "solution".  I'm more interested in knowing if anyone else has also found a workaround or if the authors of those two packages are interested in keeping up with the new CV standards to come.

Comment: "Don't look at me" :(

Comment: Essentially asking for a large amount of work: off topic or too broad!

Comment: I have just released an updated version of europecv that implements the graphical theme released in July 2013. More info here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196533/59992

Comment: It is humble request please the add the Skype ICON in europass CV. In these days every Master and PhD candidate wants because almost every institute demanding. So my idea is to add the skype icon in europecv2013.cls