# LaTeX class for europass cv (2013 template)

Tags: europecv

Does anyone know if there is a LaTeX class which implements the new (2013) europass cv?

I could not find anything on the web and I am thinking to start writing it myself but I want to make sure that there is nothing like that around. This question was already asked in [Europass 2013 Curriculum Vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122995/europass-2013-curriculum-vitae) and apparently no such class existed up to 4 October.

Comment: I have been looking at that myself and started work on a new europecv package with the new template but real work got in the way. I have made the new icons into a font and was looking at either reworking the current package or using moderncv as a staring point. The problem with the current europecv package is the lack of straight forward support for things like xelatex/lualatex/biblatex... Other things I would like to correct is fact that the current package does not use the standard sectioning method. So yeah work in progress from my part and maybe someone else will beat me to it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have just released an updated version of `europecv` that implements the graphical theme released in July 2013.

You can see a sample CV [here](https://github.com/leinardi/europecv2013/blob/master/examples/CV-Example-1-en_EN.pdf) and its source [here](https://github.com/leinardi/europecv2013/blob/master/examples/CV-Example-1-en_EN.tex).

The class and all related files are hosted on github: https://github.com/leinardi/europecv2013

Normally I do not work with LaTeX (but I like to use it when I get the chance), which is why the class code may not be very clean.
If anyone has suggestions on how to improve the code I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! And it would be great if you can put yourself in this list here http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/